# Need to list the file names in remote server using sftpc

Tags: powershell

I need to list the file names in a remote server using the PSFTP command.

```
sftpc -profile=remote_server_profile.tlp -cmd=ls location
```

This command is not giving any output. Does anyone know what may cause this?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#6.2.10), you need to use `dir` to list the remote files, not `ls`.

Comment: The name of the [PSFTP](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter6.html) command is not `sftpc`, and it doesn't have options `-profile` or `-cmd`. Are you using the [Bitvise](http://www.bitvise.com/) SFTP client?